# Python GUI freezes or closes while trying to update the button label text

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk, freeze

I am trying to read a string from the ubuntu terminal and set that string as a label of a button. It works perfectly for some iteration and then freezes or closes with error. I couldn't find any pattern about when it freezes or closes. I am using gtk libraries and python 2.7.

A screenshot of the UI after it has frozen can be seen below.

[image: Screenshot of the frozen UI(with error)]

As seen in the above screenshot, it has successfully updated the value 234, 56 and then exited with error after receiving 213 string. You can also observe that the button in the UI also has 213 value.

Sometimes the UI just freezes without displaying any errors or exiting.

I have used the below codes

*1.* thread.py *( main program called from terminal )*

```
import thread
import time
import gui2
import vkeys1
import os   
try:
    thread.start_new_thread( vkeys1.main, ( ) )
    thread.start_new_thread( gui2.main, ( ) )  
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

# To stop this script from closing
os.system("mkfifo d1 2> error.log")
fd = os.open('d1', os.O_RDONLY)
ch = os.read(fd,1)   # No writer
```

*2.* vkeys1.py *( It reads the input from terminal and calls textinit() )*

```
import gui2
def main() :
    while True:
        try :           
            gui2.ch = str(input('\nInput a string :   '))
            gui2.textinit()
        except :
            print(" \n\n Exception!! \n\n")
```

*3.* gui2.py *( Updates the button label )*

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, Gdk, GLib
import Image
import os, sys
import time
import vkeys1
import threading

global ch   # ch is used at vkeys1.py to store the input
ch = 'dummy content'

button0 = Gtk.Button(label="Initially empty")

class TableWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="String retrieval widget")  
        self.set_size_request(500,200)
        self.connect_after('destroy', self.destroy) 
        self.main_box=Gtk.VBox()
        self.main_box.set_spacing(5)

        self.label = Gtk.Label(" ") 

        table = Gtk.Table(7,4, True)
        self.add(self.main_box)
        self.main_box.pack_start(self.label, False, False, 0)
        self.main_box.pack_start(table, False, False, 0) 

        table.attach(button0, 0, 4, 0, 1)
        self.show_all()

    def destroy(window, self):
        Gtk.main_quit()


def textinit():     # called from vkeys1.py
        class Thrd(threading.Thread) :
            def __init__(self) :
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                print('\nReceived string')
                print(str(ch))
                print('\n')
                button0.set_label(str(ch))  # Button label updated here         
    Thrd2 = Thrd()
    Thrd2.start()
    return          

def main():
    app=TableWindow()   
    app.set_keep_above(True)    
    app.set_gravity(Gdk.Gravity.SOUTH_WEST) 
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":# for any error exit
    sys.exit(main())
```

The above codes can be run by typing `python thread.py` (after creating the above 3 files off-course). Please suggest any solution to overcome this freezing problem.

Comment: **Never** call GTK functions from thread other than the same thread that runs the main loop. Instead, use `GLib.idle_add(...)` to schedule execution of the function in the GUI thread. Also, the `Thrd` class in `gui2` is useless, since you never define the `run` method.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to add `Glib.idle_add()` , but it didn't work. Maybe, I am still doing something wrong. I'm new to python and UI. Can you please post the modified code as answer, so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: Have you fixed other problems with your example? First, you should get rid       of the generic exception handler which just prints "Exception!!!!"; removing it will provide the actual backtrace. (When running with Python 2, I had to change `input` to `raw_input`, otherwise it raised on arbitrary strings.) Also, `vkey1` contained syntax errors. Once I fixed these errors, replaced the unnecessary thread creation in `textinit` with a simple call to `button0.set_label(str(ch))`, and replaced the call to `gui2.textinit()` with `GLib.idle_add(gui2.textinit)`, your example worked just fine.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you. It works for atleast 30 iterations. Is there any way to call `gui2.textinit()` without using `GLib.idle_add()` ? Actually, now I have added some extra code and now it doesn't call `gui2.textinit()` as it is not in idle. The problem is that I need `gui2.textinit()` to be called immediately.

Comment: @user4815162342 Sorry. I couldn't post that extra code here due to ethical reasons. Please tell me if there is any way to call the function immediately ( i.e. without using idle function). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is [not allowed](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html) to use GTK from threads other than the one that runs the main loop. What exactly is wrong with using `GLib.idle_add` to run the function in the GUI thread? If the main loop is ready to process events, the function should execute instantaneously. To have a chance of someone answering the question, please consider posting a minimal example that demonstrates the actual  problem you are having.

Comment: @user4815162342 Sorry for the trouble. I corrected the problem. My original code was reading the string from fifo file, and it was waiting for the string sometimes, which delayed the call to `GLib.idle_add(gui2.textinit)`. Thank you for the `idle_add()` answer(comment). Post it as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of the crash is that your code invokes GTK code from threads other than the thread that runs the main loop, which the [documentation states](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html) is not allowed.

To resolve the issue, replace the call of `gui2.textinit()` with `GLib.idle_add(gui2.textinit)` (note the lack of parentheses after `textinit`).

Several remarks about the code:

- The generic exception handler is masking exceptions that occur. Remove it, and you will see a useful traceback when something goes wrong.
- If you are running under Python 2, you probably want to change `input` to `raw_input`, otherwise the code chokes on any input that is not a valid Python expression.
- `textinit` creates a thread object that never runs an actual thread. When inheriting from `threading.Thread`, one must override the `run` function, which will be invoked in the new thread once `start()` is called. Doing the work in the constructor accomplishes nothing.
- `thread.start_new_thread` is a low-level API that should not be used in normal circumstances and that is demoted to `_thread` in Python 3. Instead of `thread.start_new_thread(fn, ())`, use `threading.Thread(target=fn)`, which has the same meaning, and also returns a `Thread` object.